appendZoneText​(TextStyle textStyle, Set<ZoneId> preferredZones) DateTimeFormatterBuilder java
DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();

// Append date and time components
builder.append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

// Append zone text with preferred zones
builder.appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, Set.of(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"),ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")));

// Create the DateTimeFormatter
DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter();

// Format a date and time
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
String formattedText = dateTime.format(formatter);

// Print the formatted text
System.out.println(formattedText);

If I provide a zone that is not in the prefferedset, I find that makes no difference.
What happens if I provide a zone that is not in prefferedset?

If you provide a time zone that is not in the preferred set (i.e., one that isn't Asia/Tokyo or America/Los_Angeles), the formatter will still display the zone text, but in the default text style (SHORT, in your case), instead of using any specific format based on your preferred set.
If the zone is in the preferred set:

The DateTimeFormatter will use the short text style (e.g., "PDT" for
"America/Los_Angeles").

If the zone is not in the preferred set:

The formatter still formats the zone text but it just doesn't restrict
itself to your specified preferred zones. The formatting falls back to
the general formatting rules for zone text.

For example, if you format a time zone like Europe/London which is not in the preferred set, it would still display the short name for that zone (e.g., BST for British Summer Time).

Thank you @Superman , but i tried  by changing TextStyle.SHORT to TextStye.FULL in code , but if i provided a zone that is NOT in prefferedset that is also formatting inTextStyle,FULL.

It is because the TextStyle defines how the zone is displayed (full or short text), but the preferred set only helps the formatter decide which zone names to prefer if there are multiple options available. When the provided zone is not in the preferred set, it will still be formatted using the TextStyle you defined (in this case, FULL). Can you please tell what is your input and what is expected?

can you please explain  meaning of  "the formatter decide which zone names to prefer if there are multiple options available"

The documentation of appendZoneText doesn't mention anything about what the preferred set of zone IDs will do during formatting, so they probably doesn't do anything during formatting.
The set of preferred zone IDs does play a role during parsing. From the documentation:

During formatting, (doesn't mention anything relevant here)
During parsing, either the textual zone name, the zone ID or the offset is accepted. Many textual zone names are not unique, such as CST can be for both "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time". In this situation, the zone id will be determined by the region information from formatter's locale and the standard zone id for that area, for example, America/New_York for the America Eastern zone. This method also allows a set of preferred ZoneId to be specified for parsing. The matched preferred zone id will be used if the textural zone name being parsed is not unique.

The set is used to resolve a zone ID when the text in the string to be parsed  is ambiguous. After all, there are a lot of ambiguities in time zone abbreviations, like the "CST" example in the documentation. As another example, consider "BST"
DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
builder.append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
builder.appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, Set.of(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")));
// I've set the locale explicitly so that you can reproduce this regardless of your system locale
DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter().withLocale(Locale.UK);
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2024-09-29 16:12:00BST", formatter));

This produces a ZonedDateTime in the zone Europe/London because it is in the set of preferred zones.
If I leave the set of preferred zone IDs empty, the zone is parsed as Pacific/Bougainville instead. "BST" is a valid abbreviation for both of the time zones (British Summer Time, Bougainville Standard Time).
You can find a list of English time zone abbreviations here. Try parsing text with some of the non-unique ones there, and observe how changing the set of preferred time zones changes the parse result.
